# Invalid static_cast from struct to char*

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, char

I am trying to do a uni assignment (first year), where the task is to read in a file filled with records (in this case fake student records), insert them into a struct array in the code, write that struct array to a .dat file, and then read the file back in and verify it.

I keep getting an error about converting my struct to a char* (line 155)

Please don't be too technical with the answer, as I have only been coding for a few months ahah

```
/* 
 * File:   lab3.cpp
 * Author: tom
 *
 * Created on August 19, 2015, 12:02 AM
 */
#include<iostream>
#include<cstring>
#include<fstream>

using namespace std;

//Structure declaration area
struct marks // A structure for user data
{
    int studentnumber;
    float ass1;
    float ass2;
    float ass3;
    float ass4;
    int labs;
    float exam;
    float total;
};

//Function Prototyping
void structinsert(ifstream&);
void binarywrite(ofstream&);
int binaryread(ifstream& , marks);

//Global Array for student marks
marks students [100];

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    ifstream fin;
    ofstream fout;
    int recordsread = 0;

    fin.open(argv[1]); //Input file opened from cmdline args
    fout.open(argv[2]); // Output file opened from cmdline args

    if (fin.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Input file not found. Terminating..." << endl;
    }

    else if (fout.fail())
    {
        cerr << "Output file not found. Terminating..." << endl;
    }

    else
    {
        structinsert(fin);//Function which places data into the global "student" array
        binarywrite(fout);

        fin.close();
        fout.close();
        fin.open(argv[2]);

        int cnt = 0;
        while((!fin.eof()) && (cnt < 100))
        {
            fin.read(static_cast<char *>(&students[cnt]), sizeof(marks));
            cnt++;
        }

        cout << "Records Read: " << recordsread << endl;

    }

    return 0;
}

void structinsert(ifstream& input)
{
    float temp;
    float value;

    // Ignore first line of headings
    input.ignore(150, '\n');

    for (int x = 0; x < 100; x++)
    {
        input >> students[x].studentnumber;
        input.ignore (1);
        temp = input.peek();
        if (temp == '\t')
        {
                input.ignore(1,'\t');
                students[x].ass1 = 0;
        }
        else
        {
                input >> students[x].ass1;
                input.ignore(1,'\t');
        }

        temp = input.peek();
        if (temp == '\t')
        {
                input.ignore(1,'\t');
                students[x].ass2 = 0;
        }
        else
        {
                input >> students[x].ass2;
                input.ignore(1,'\t');
        }

        temp = input.peek();
        if (temp == '\t')
        {
                input.ignore(1,'\t');
                students[x].ass3 = 0;
        }
        else
        {
                input >> students[x].ass3;
                input.ignore(1,'\t');
        }

        temp = input.peek();
        if (temp == '\t')
        {
                input.ignore(1,'\t');
                students[x].ass4= 0;
        }
        else
        {
                input >> students[x].ass4;
                input.ignore(1,'\t');
        }

        input >> students[x].labs;
        input.ignore(1,'\t');

        temp = input.peek();
        if (temp == '\n')
        {
                input.ignore(1,'\t');
                students[x].exam = 0;
        }
        else
        {
                input >> students[x].exam;
                input.ignore(1,'\t');
        }
    }
}

void binarywrite(ofstream& output)
{
    output.write(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&students),100*sizeof(marks));
}
```

Comment: You need to use `reinterpret_cast` (or a double `static_cast`, first to `void*`, but `reinterpret_cast` does the same thing here) to cast incompatible pointer types, which oddly enough you've already done in `binarywrite`.

Comment: Oh I tried that before, because I originally had a function called 'binarywrite' but I could not get it to work for the life of me. I guess I just never tried interpret in my main function! Thankyou @user657267